# Can you iterate over caches managed by `org.ehcache.CacheManager`?

Tags: ehcache

Is it possible to iterate over caches managed by `org.ehcache.CacheManager`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but the typed API means you have to go through the configuration information, to get the right key and value type for a give cache alias:

```
Configuration configuration = cacheManager.getRuntimeConfiguration();
for (Map.Entry<String, CacheConfiguration<?, ?>> entry : configuration.getCacheConfigurations().entrySet()) {
  CacheConfiguration<?, ?> cacheConfig = entry.getValue();
  Cache<?, ?> cache = cacheManager.getCache(entry.getKey(), cacheConfig.getKeyType(), cacheConfig.getValueType());
}
```